# Delphi clientdataset: speeding up removing records from one data set based on another

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

Currently I have two datasets. One has all required documents for a set of jobs; the other has documents that are present. I need the missing requirements, that is, documents from the first dataset that aren't in the second. (Problems in the underlying SQL data structure prevent querying just the missing docs without using excessively slow subqueries).

I've attempted to remove the docs that are present from the required doc dataset so it only contains what's missing.

```
try
  with cdsAllDocs do begin
    while not eof do begin
      cdsFilter(cdsRequiredDocs, 'JobID = ' + fieldByName('JobID').AsString + ' AND ID = ' + fieldByName('PREDEFINEDDOCID').AsString);
      while cdsRequiredDocs.RecordCount > 0 do cdsRequiredDocs.Delete;
      next;
    end; // while not eof
  end; // with cdsAllDocs 
finally
  cdsFilterClear(cdsRequiredDocs);
end;
```

I haven't bothered to disable controls because neither dataset has any associated controls.

The problem is that this approach is terribly slow. In a situation with ~7000 required documents, this process is taking ~2.25 seconds to get my trimmed down list.

Is there a way to do what I am trying to do here in a more efficient way? (Apart from fixing the SQL data which is currently out of my control). Thanks.

**Addition following several comments below:**
Several are suggesting that a better query up front could get a single dataset and avoid this problem in the first: Here are the actual queries:
This one gets the list of all requirements:

```
SELECT distinct
  J.JobID,
  P.PREDEFINEDDOCID as ID
FROM JOBTEMPLATECONTEXT JT
Join DEPARTMENTJOB DJ
  on DJ.jobid = JT.JobID
  and DJ.DepartmentJobFetch = "Y"
  and UPPER(DJ.DEPARTMENTJOBSTATUS) in ("ACTIVE", "PENDING")
Join Job J
  on JT.JOBID = J.JOBID
  and J.JOBFETCH = "Y"
Join TEMPLATECONTEXT T
  on T.TEMPLATECONTEXTID = JT.TEMPLATECONTEXTID
  and JT.CONTEXTDUEDATE < "Now"
join PREDEFINEDDOC P on P.PREDEFINEDDOCID = T.TEMPCONTEXTID
```

And this one (which is extremely slow) gets the documents that are there:

```
SELECT distinct
  J.JobID, P.PREDEFINEDDOCID
FROM Job J
Join JOBTEMPLATECONTEXT JT
  on JT.jobid = J.JobID
  and J.JobFetch = "Y"
Join DEPARTMENTJOB DJ
  on DJ.JOBID = J.JOBID
  and DJ.DepartmentJobFetch = "Y"
  and UPPER(DJ.DEPARTMENTJOBSTATUS) in ("ACTIVE", "PENDING")
Join TEMPLATECONTEXT T
  on T.TEMPLATECONTEXTID = JT.TEMPLATECONTEXTID
join PREDEFINEDDOC P on P.PREDEFINEDDOCID = T.TEMPCONTEXTID
join JOBDOCUMENTS JD
  on JT.JOBID = JD.JOBID
join DOCUMENTS D
  on D.PredefinedDocID = P.PREDEFINEDDOCID
  and D.DOCUMENTFETCH = "Y"
  and JD.DOCUMENTID = D.DOCUMENTID
```

Please do not respond by telling me that storing values I'm limiting by in varChars instead of enumerated types is bad, or that the tangle of tables is bad db design; I don't have control of that.

Comment: Have you tried cdsRequiredDocs.[LogChanges](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Datasnap.DBClient.TCustomClientDataSet.LogChanges) := False;?

Comment: I would still go for a proper initial query. Can you tell us the type of database, the table structures and the desired outcome? Perhaps someone can formulate a query with better performance.

Comment: I agree with @UweRaabe. If - as you say - the structure is out of your control perhaps it's still possible to optimize the query with indexes and/or a fine-tuned execution plan.

Comment: It's a firebird 2.5 db but there's no value that lets one join the required docs with the present docs. Very bad db design but I can't change it. Add subqueries turns what is 1 second of data gathering to 30 seconds plus.

Comment: From your comments so far (using subqueries) it seems it should be possible to rewrite the query to get your results directly (just my 2c).

Comment: I hadn't tried .LogChanges; just did and it didn't make any measurable difference

Comment: Another possibility on the client side would be to define temporary indexes (one-time cost) to speed up repeated filtering.

Comment: @Eric So what you're showing on the client datasets: JobID = JobID and ID = PredefinedDocID is not possible on the tables themselves? Are there some calculated fields based on data outside of the database?

Comment: Getting the JobID and PredefinedDocID are both possible in the DB, but they involve connecting half a dozen tables, some of which are joined on non-indexed fields and which have some design problems. In order to find the records not in the other table, I have to do a left join and select null values. This is doable, but doing the left join on what is already an extremely slow query proves to be painfully slow. (20 or 30 times slower than doing the two separate queries.)

Comment: Is there a unique numeric document id for each document?  I'm asking because I am wondering whether you are going about this the right way: the use of `FieldByName` and `RecordCount` in a tight loop dseems to suggest not.

Comment: I have added the actual SQL queries for those who are contending that I should just actually fix the queries.

Comment: That looks like some pretty moderate queries with very few joins. (I could show you a "tangle of tables" ;-)) This ought to be pretty fast. Perhaps all you need to do is create a few indexes in the database. Can you do that? That would solve the problem and save you from having to deal with it on the client.

Comment: So the goal would be to get something like this running with acceptable performance:
`SELECT distinct
  J.JobID,
  P.PREDEFINEDDOCID as ID
FROM JOBTEMPLATECONTEXT JT
... /* omitted for lack of space */
left outer join JOBDOCUMENTS JD
  on JT.JOBID = JD.JOBID
left outer join DOCUMENTS D
  on D.PredefinedDocID = P.PREDEFINEDDOCID
  and D.DOCUMENTFETCH = "Y"
  and JD.DOCUMENTID = D.DOCUMENTID
where
  D.DOCUMENTID IS NULL`

Comment: Yeah, I've got much more tangled queries too. :) What bugs me about these is that a lot of the intervening tables are just for joining but aren't really needed based on the actual relationships. I'll go after the person who controls the db and fight for the indexes after I figure out which are missing. (I know how to add indexes, but I don't have control here.)

Comment: @OndrejKelle: Yup. That's how I originally wrote it and the indexing problems caused it to take a few minutes to return a few hundred records. :(

Comment: I feel your pain. :-/ So if you're absolutely stuck with having to deal with it on the client you could try to create some indexes on the client dataset. Also as @MartynA said avoid FieldByName in loops (initialize local TField variables before the loop).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a filter set IndexFieldNames to JobID for each dataset. Then you can loop through each dataset once. That is much faster than applying a filter thousands of times.

```
var
  RequiredKey: string;
  AllKey: string;
  // I'm also assuming that Fields were created on the CDS - i.e. cdsRequiredDocsJobId, etc.


cdsRequiredDocs.IndexFieldNames := 'JobID;ID'; 
cdsAllDocs.IndexFieldNames := 'JobID;PREDEFINEDDOCID';

cdsRequiredDocs.First;
cdsAllDocs.First;

while (not cdsRequiredDocs.Eof) and (not cdsAllDocs.Eof) do 
begin
  RequiredKey := cdsRequiredDocsJobId.AsString + cdsRequiredDocsId.AsString;
  AllKey := cdsAllDocsJobId.AsString + cdsAllDocsPreDefinedDocId.AsString;

  // Move through AllDocs until we find a key that is equal or greater 
  // to the one in RequiredDocs
  while AllKey < RequiredKey do
  begin
    cdsAllDocs.Next;
    AllKey := cdsAllDocsJobId.AsString + cdsAllDocsPreDefinedDocId.AsString;      
    if cdsAllDocs.Eof then  
      break;
  end;

  // If we stopped on a key that matches then we need to 
  // delete our row, otherwise we move to the next one to check
  if AllKey = RequiredKey then
  begin
    cdsRequiredDocs.Delete;
    // We will be on the next record already - unless this was the 
    // last record in the CDS, then we will move back one. This can cause an 
    // extra pass through the loop, but since we only delete when the key matches
    // it should not cause anything to be removed that should stay
  end
  else
  begin
    cdsRequiredDocs.Next;
  end;

end; // while not eof
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Set Range (which requires an index be set) is much faster than applying a filter. If you know that only a single row matches you can also use GotoKey instead of SetRange.

You will also speed things up if you replace the FieldByName calls with Field objects that are set before the loop, either by creating them as part of the CDS or saving them off before the loop.

```
try
  cdsRequiredDocs.IndexFieldNames := 'JobId;ID';

  with cdsAllDocs do begin
    while not eof do begin
      cdsRequiredDocs.SetRange([fieldByName('JobID').AsString, fieldByName('PREDEFINEDDOCID').AsString],
                               [fieldByName('JobID').AsString, fieldByName('PREDEFINEDDOCID').AsString]);

      while cdsRequiredDocs.RecordCount > 0 do cdsRequiredDocs.Delete;
      next;
    end; // while not eof
  end; // with cdsAllDocs 
finally
  cdsRequiredDocs.CancelRange;
end;
```